# Creating a worksheet from Apache POI deprecated methods

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to create a worksheet using `HSSFSheet` from `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*`, but when I use some of the methods my Eclipse IDE is yelling that it is deprecated. For example, it is yelling that the `setColumnWidth` method is deprecated:

```
HSSFSheet workSheet = workBook.createSheet("CPNI");
workSheet.setColumnWidth((short) 0, (short) (230 * ABOUT_ONE_PIXEL_WIDE));
```

However, when I look at the `HSSFSheet` API documentation, it doesn't list it as deprecated nor the other methods that my IDE is yelling at so I am not sure why my IDE is yelling that the methods are deprecated.

I am using the `poi-3.13.jar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I extract the javadoc for poi 3.13 it says the following

> void    setColumnWidth(short columnIndex, short width)
>
> Deprecated. (Sep 2008) use setColumnWidth(int, int)

You're probably reading an online documentation for the latest version where this function has been removed (after being deprecated for a long while)

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html

So to fix this particular error you shouldn't cast it to `short`

It's always a good idea to read the documentation for the version you are using. The IDE should be ale to pull this from the `maven` repository automatically.

If it doesn't do this you can always extract the javadocs yourself.

Download `poi-3.13-javadoc.jar` from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi/3.13/
and unzip it

Comment: Than you kind sir!